# Nextjs 13 app directory taking too much ram on nodejs Javascript Run time around 2.5GB

Tags: next.js, next.js13

[image]
I'm experiencing a significant increase in RAM usage (around 2 to 3 GB) when running Next.js version 13 projects located in the app directory. In contrast, projects in the pages directory, even after upgrading to version 13.3.5 and Node.js 18.16.0, only use a maximum of 500MB.

Upgrading to the latest versions didn't resolve the issue, and I'm hesitant to switch to the pages directory due to the extensive work done in the app directory. Additionally, the build time in the app directory is approximately 1 minute, affecting my coding productivity.

Any insights or suggestions on optimizing RAM usage and build times in the app directory would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using getServerSideSession for login and admin validation, next auth.js in app directory and API making with app directory ,and framer motion for animation

Comment: Check out this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46756) on github, it is about memory issues with the development server, also if you are using react-icons or MUI that may be the cause.

Comment: Thanks, man I switch from react-icons to react-lucid and use shadcn for the UI component and it reduced memory usage to half but still had 3-4 times higher memory usage and build time compare to the pages directory.

Comment: That is possible, I also have observed a higher memory usage when using app dir compared to pages. But that may be the overhead from using RSC, since server components run on the server e.g use machine resources.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also experiencing this problem. Nextjs keeps consuming memory until I run out of memory or my PC gets frozen or inopperable